# Sony Smartwatch - How to change font size in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, sony-smartwatch

I am developing an app on sony smartwatch, and I started off with the SampleNotificationExtension example. I would like to change the font size of my notification. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please give some sample code.

Comment: Sorry, as I dont know where and how to change the font, I also have no idea what sample code I should give there - the SampleNotificationExtension example contains a lot of code..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change the font of notifications. You only supply the information that is to be notified (into the Smart Connect notification database) and then it is up to each individual Sony Mobile smart accessory to render the notification on the device.